# Area chart based on query in Kibana 4

Tags: charts, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch

I have build system for couple components with some branches and some jobs on these branches. Typical JSON for event look more or less like that (I removed unrelated information):

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.04.08",
  "_type": "time",
  "_id": "AUyeQ2u19d6vbBbSmlDE",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2015-04-08T02:34:17.000Z",
    "column6": "component1",
    "column7": "trunk",
    "column8": "['x86', 'UT']",
    "column10": 500
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1428460457000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1428460457000
  ]
}
```

I would like to build [Area Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_chart) based on following query: one particular branch (column7) AND one particular component (column6). Each job type (column8) would contribute with value located in column10. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an Area Chart with the Y axis being the Sum, Average, Min, or Max of `column10`.

Next on the X axis, create a Date Histogram on the `@timestamp` field.

Add a sub-aggregation that is a `split area` aggregation with either a `terms`  or a `filter` sub-aggregation.  If you choose the `terms`, select field `column6` and how many values you want to see.

If you choose the `filter` aggregation, you can enter as many filters as you like (so you don't have to rely on the terms).  For example, if you only want to see two specific values from `column6`. you could put one filter of `column6:component1` and another of `column6:component2`.